# Запись через System Calls C# Mono Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net, mono, posix

Пытаюсь записать целочисленное значение по системному адресу Linux

> /sys/class/backlight/backlight/brightness

Использую Mono Posix. Что-то делаю не верно, так как выскакивает ошибка Invalid argument [EINVAL]. Возможно не правильно записываю значение.

Подключаю динамические библиотеки:

```
    [DllImport("libc.so.6", EntryPoint = "open")]
    public static extern int Open(string fileName, int mode);

    [DllImport("libc.so.6", EntryPoint = "fcntl", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int Fcntl(int fd, int request, int data);

private const string Path = "/sys/class/backlight/backlight/brightness";
    private int fd = -1;
```

Далее открываю "файл":

```
private void Open()
    {
        fd = Syscall.open(Path, OpenFlags.O_RDWR);

        if (fd < 0)
        {
            CheckAndThrowUnixIOException();
        }
    }
```

И пробую записать:

```
 public unsafe void WriteValue(int value)
    {
        Open();

        var ret = Fcntl(fd, 1, value); // что - то тут не так

        int count;
        var data = new char[1];
        data[0] = (char) value; // и тут тоже что-то не правильно? Нужно значение в IntPtr.

        fixed(char* p = data)
        {
            count = (int)Syscall.write(fd, p, (ulong) data.Length);
        }


        if (count < 0)
        {
            CheckAndThrowUnixIOException(); // Соответственно тут летит ошибка.
        }
    }
```

Метод проброса исключений:

```
 private void CheckAndThrowUnixIOException()
    {
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new UnixIOException(error);
    }
```

Не могу сообразить как записать значение в sys/class.... Так же не ясно, как можно прочитать по адресу из константы Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было в качестве указателя передавать строковый литерал:

```
 [DllImport("libc.so.6", EntryPoint = "open")]
 public static extern int Open(string fileName, int mode);

 private void Open()
    {
        fileDescriptor = Syscall.open(BrightnessPath, OpenFlags.O_RDWR);

        if (fileDescriptor < 0) CheckAndThrowUnixIOException();
    }

    private void OpenIfNotOpen()
    {
        if (!IsOpen) Open();
    }

 public unsafe void WriteBrightnessValue(int value)
    {
        if (value <= MaxBrightness)
        {
            var buffer = value.Map(value);
            var str = buffer.ToString();

            OpenIfNotOpen();

            int fdValue;
            fixed (char* ptStr = str)
            {
                fdValue = (int) Syscall.write(fileDescriptor, ptStr, (ulong) str.Length);
            }

            if (fdValue < 0)
            {
                CheckAndThrowUnixIOException();
            }

            Close();

            Logger.Debug("-- File descriptor has been closed");
        }
    }
```